# Restrict method with Outlook returning nothing

Tags: delphi, outlook, calendar, exchange-server

Trying to work out how to create the right filter for the restrict method. I am trying to only show the calendar appointments for a particular user. I have so far got it to show all appointments for a date filter, but ideally need to filter only the organiser. I have tried something like `RestrictString := ('[requiredAttendees] = 'Joe Bloggs');`, but it doesn't work.

Below is my code to list all appointments and show the appointment organiser (required attendees), as well as subject and start times etc. But I'd like to only do this for a given person.

```
  Namespace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI'); // represents a NameSpace object.
  Recipient := Namespace.CreateRecipient('shared@mailbox.com');
  Recipient.Resolve;
  Folder := Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, olFolderCalendar);
  Items := Folder.Items;

  Items.Sort('[Start]', true);
  Items.IncludeRecurrences := true;

   RestrictString :=
   '@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" like ''%joe bloggs%''';

  RestrItems := Items.Restrict(RestrictString);
  Memo1.clear;
  if (RestrItems.count = 0) then Memo1.lines.add('No appointments');

  for i := 1 to RestrItems.count do
  begin

    Appointment := Items.Item(i);

    Memo1.lines.add(' ');
    Memo1.lines.add(Appointment.requiredAttendees);
    Memo1.lines.add(Appointment.subject);
    Memo1.lines.add(Appointment.Start);
    Memo1.lines.add(Appointment.End);
    Memo1.lines.add(' ');

  end;

  Outlook := UnAssigned;
```

Any pointers most appreciated. I've looked through various other questions and documentation, but have not quite grasped it yet.

Answer (score 2):

`Restrict`/`Find` methods in Outlook Object Model do not create a subrestriction on recipients (or attachments). You can do that in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), but not in Outlook Object Model.

The best you can do in OOM is to search on the `PR_DISPLAY_TO` Extended MAPI property (you can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) if you click the IMessage button). It corresponds to the `To` property in OOM and is populated with the ";" separated display names of recipients when the item is saved. It may or may not include the email addresses. The following query should work for `Items.Restrict` in your case

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" like '%Joe Bloggs%'
```

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it versions of [RDOItems](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Restrict`/`Find` do create subrestrictions on recipient name / address / SMTP address (you can specify `To`, `CC`, `BCC`, or `Recipients` in the SQL query).

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry Streblechenko for your advise. I have tried adding that sql to my restrict string. It runs with no error but it is still displaying many different appointments from multiple different people, rather than Joe Bloggs.

Comment: Is Joe Bloggs an attendee in those appointments?

Comment: So he would be the person that made the appointment, I have used `.requiredAttendees` because that's the only way I managed to show who the person is that created the appointment. I don't need to know any other attendees, just the person who created it, so that I can then search for appointments by this person.

Comment: In that case you want `PR_SENDER_NAME` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001F`) or `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001F`).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both in my string but nothing is being returned. Have I formatted this correctly: `RestrictString :=
     '@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001F" like ''%Joe Bloggs%''';`

Comment: Have you looked at the appointment that are supposed to match with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: Will it show that if I don't have the shared mailbox added to my outlook?

Comment: It will if you use File | Open | Other User's Folder.

Comment: You can also run the following script from "Script" in OutlookSpy: - it will show IMAPIFolder obejct and you can open appointments from the GetContentsTable tab

`set Recipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient("shared@mailbox.com")
Recipient.Resolve
set Folder = Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, olFolderCalendar)
BrowseObject(Folder.MAPIOBJECT)`

Comment: Hi Dmitry,  in IMessage for an appointment it shows the name of the `appointment.requiredattendees` under these property tags: `PidNameKeywords`, `AllAttendeesString`, `ToAttendeesString`, `PR_DISPLAY_TO_W`. I tried all of their DSAL in my `restrictstring` but it still just shows all appointments still.

Comment: Does it only fail for the delegate Calendar folder? Does it work for the primary mailbox?

Comment: So the problem is that you get too many positive hits, not that you get none or too few?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yes the problem is that the filter is not filtering to show the appointments from the user specified in the restrict string.

Comment: The idea is to display the appointments that that person has made. But it is showing every appointment from every user, rather than Joe Bloggs

Comment: OK, so you are getting too many matches, right? Is the user in question (Joe Bloggs) is an attendee on all of these meetings, then your result is expected, isn't it?

Comment: Basically there are lots of different people creating appointments in this mailbox. It's a department in a company. Joe bloggs is just one of those people in the department who creates appointments. At present it's showing his, along with all other people in that department. So it's listing all people in that mailbox still, even with the joe bloggs filter. He is not an attendee of the other appointments. I had to use . thanks for your continued help

Comment: What is your lattes code that return the items that should not be returned?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I've updated the code in my original post to show my latest version. It returns all appointments for every attendee (appointment creator), rather than just joe blogg's. Joe blogs does also show in this list too, but I only want it to show his, not everyone.

Comment: Is "Joe Bloggs" the owner of the mailbox?

Comment: It's a sharedmailbox that is used for bookings in office365. they just have the permission to create appointments I guess.